# Conditional class rendering based on state for mapped items

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

https://codesandbox.io/s/vjonpw8xzl
(not responsive, view in new window/fullpage to see correctly)

desired result: when clicking the down(expand)icon on each card, they operate independently of each other, opening/closing the expanded menu `className: expanded` by toggling on the `className: 'show'` and `className: 'hide'`

whats happening: the state in app is getting updated, when the expand icon is clicked, and all of the expanded menus are opening in unison.

i understand why this is happening, i just don't know how to fix it.

if it were my own data, i'd add this to each object in state

```
isExpanded:false
```

and toggle it, but since a load of data is coming in from an API i don't know how to do this. any help is appreciated.

Comment: To write a good question, please include the impacted code in question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling your state logic for `isExpanded` in the `App` component you can move it to the `Character` component and remove all `isExpanded` / `toggleExpanded` props.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide that which states are actually defining the component and are needed for it. As `isExpanded` & `toggleExpanded` are something specific to `character` component they should reside in that component.